# PHP preg_split store into multiple variables

Tags: php, explode

I am new to PHP and need some assistance.

I have an input string that looks like this: `968:-50px, 750:-300px, 590:-500px`

These can be thought of as 3 items each with 2 values: `a:b, a:b, a:b`

I'm currently using `explode()` but I know it's not correct. I think `preg_split()` might be the correct function to use?

Using the `a:b` example, here is some code:

```
      $string = '968:-50px, 750:-300px, 590:-500px'
      $array = explode( ',', $string );

      foreach ( $array as $a ) {
        echo '
        @media only screen and (max-width: '.$a.'px) {
          .div {
            background-position: '.$b.';
          }
        }'; $array[] = $a;
      }
```

How do I extract the value for `$b` and pass that to the loop?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why does `explode` not work for you? Why do you feel that is incorrect?

Comment: In the above code I am only getting 3 values

ie:
`968:-50px` and `750:-300px` and `590:-500px`

I need each of those to be split into 2 values that can be passed to the loop.

ie, foreach
`$a = 968`
`$b = -50px`

`$a = 750`
`$b = -300px`


`$a = 590`
`$b = -500px`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to explode each of your results again inside the loop.

```
$string = '968:-50px, 750:-300px, 590:-500px'
$array = explode( ',', $string );

foreach ( $array as $a ) {
    $ab = explode(':', $a);
    echo '@media only screen and (max-width: '.$ab[0].'px) {
        .div {
            background-position: '.$ab[1].';
            }
        }'; 
    $array[] = $a;
}
```